# Url rewrite not working; 404 error and no url change

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a website where I want the url

```
    www.example.com/directory1/states/california.php
```

to point to

```
    www.example.com/directory1/california
```

And a similar url change for the city pages as well:

```
   www.example.com/directory1/cities/miami.php
```

should point to

```
  www.example.com/directory1/miami
```

I'm using the following rules in my access file to change the url:

```
RewriteRule ^directory1/(alabama|alaska|arizona|arkansas|california|colorado|connecticut|delaware|florida|georgia|guam|hawaii|idaho|illinois|indiana|iowa|kansas|kentucky|louisiana|maine|maryland|massachusetts|michigan|minnesota|mississippi|missouri|montana|nationwide|nebraska|nevada|new_hampshire|new_jersey|new_mexico|new_york|north_carolina|north_dakota|ohio|oklahoma|oregon|pennsylvania|rhode_island|south_carolina|south_dakota|tennesee|texas|us_virgin_islands|utah|vermont|virginia|washington|west_virigina|wisconsin|wyoming)$ /directory1/states/$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^directory1/(.*)$ /directory1/cities/$1.php [L]
```

However, nothing changes in the url bar and I always get a 404 not found. When I tested it with the [htaccess checker](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be), the output url is always correct. What is wrong with my rules? Is there a way to test how/if mod_rewrite is even functioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some server configs require you to turn the rewrite engine on in your .htaccess file. Right at the top:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

I've also known some server configs where the file path starts/ends with a / (due to other rewrite rules already being run on the request) so perhaps allow for that to be there in the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/?directory1/(alabama|alaska|arizona|arkansas|california|colorado|connecticut|delaware|florida|georgia|guam|hawaii|idaho|illinois|indiana|iowa|kansas|kentucky|louisiana|maine|maryland|massachusetts|michigan|minnesota|mississippi|missouri|montana|nationwide|nebraska|nevada|new_hampshire|new_jersey|new_mexico|new_york|north_carolina|north_dakota|ohio|oklahoma|oregon|pennsylvania|rhode_island|south_carolina|south_dakota|tennesee|texas|us_virgin_islands|utah|vermont|virginia|washington|west_virigina|wisconsin|wyoming)/?$ /directory1/states/$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/?directory1/(.*)/?$ /directory1/cities/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Yeah, I have my rewriteengine on, and I tried to add the backslashes, but to no avail :/

Comment: Maybe try adding a rule to see if any rules are being processed in that .htaccess file. Maybe the module isn't installed or there's a file higher up stopping it. My favourite is something like:
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [F,L]
If it works you get Forbidden error page up on every URL hitting that rule.